# How to access a file with a virtual path with port?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file

I'm having a problem accessing a file with a virtual path with ports and I'm getting this error.

```
"ClassName":"System.NotSupportedException","Message":"The given path's format is not supported.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"
```

Here is my code:

```
ScriptEngine pythonEngine = Python.CreateEngine();

string samplepath = "https:\\sample.com:8404\\SampleProject\\Models\\File.py";
 ScriptSource source = pythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(samplepath);
 ScriptScope scope = pythonEngine.CreateScope();
 source.Execute(scope);
```

It's working when I remove the port but I received the error when I include the port. Noting that the virtual path is a remote server.

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings? Is the port opened in the firewall?

Comment: Its an ssl site, is it not running on port 443?

Comment: @Programnik yes, it's not running in port 443. Currently having some server problems with 443 that is why I used 8404.

Comment: @Thangdurai the port isn't opened in the firewall. Noting also that the server that I'm accessing is a remote server.

Comment: @Thangdurai I've tried opening my firewall in that port and it works now. Thank you.